# address of first string element yields unexpected result

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, memory-address

The goal is to write a function that outputs the address of the first element of a string that is equal to a character, however I am confused by the result.

When evaluating the function with a string that contains said character in the first place, I get a difference of 2 bytes between the address of the beginning of the string and the address of the first element. E.g. `0x7ffe559716d0` and `0x7ffe559716e0`.
Shouldn't the address be the same?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const char* first_char(const char* str, const char ch)
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == ch)
            return (i+str);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    string str1 = "jasdfgjhk";
    const char ch1 = 'j';
    cout << &str1 << endl;
    //should be the same address as above?
    cout << (void*)first_char(&str1[0], ch1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << &str1 << endl;` Doesn't output the address of the 1st element in the char array, try the same with `cout << (void*)str1 << endl;`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as caused by a simple typographic error because you just didn't think about how `std::string` is implemented; it's not a `char[]`, so of course its address isn't the same as the address of the first `char` in its buffer.

Comment: @gsamaras Ooops, I didn't spot that the variable is a `std::string`. So OP actually needs `cout << (void*)str1.c_str() << endl;`

Comment: I just posted an answer @user0042 and used `data()`. I suspect that `c_str()` will do the trick as well! Do you think I should include that in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
cout << &str1 << endl;
```

to this:

```
cout << (void*)str1.data() << endl;
```

and you will get the same address as the one returned by your function.

The reason is that `std::string` is not just an array of characters, it's a class, who has a data member that is an array and stores the characters of the string.

By using [`data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/), you are getting that array. When you print its address it gives you the actual address of the array, and of the class as before

Comment: you can also define a legacy char array without an object wrapped around `const char* str1 = "jasdfgjhk";`. Now `str1` is only a pointer and you can print it with `cout << (void*)str1 << endl;`. You don't need to convert to a pointer when calling your function now: `first_char(str1, ch1)`

Comment: Yes @PascalRosin that's true, that's also C! ;)

Comment: Yes, but for C pureness, you would need to print with something like `printf("%p\n", str1);` :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

```
&str
```

is the starting address of 'string' object. The string object is not the string itself. It contains a (hidden) dynamic pointer that points to the string itself. So by the above you get "something" like a pointer to a pointer to the string.

But with:

```
&str1[0]
```

you really get a pointer to the first character in the string.